# Gradle show text already defined error

Tags: android

hey guys i imported a library to my android studio project and it always fires an error that show text is already defined, here are my dependencies and classpath if you can help me I'd be delighted

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha5' //classpath


compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
compile('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-google-http-client:1.4.14') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}
compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax'
}
compile files('libs/speedchecker-android-sdk-1.2.jar')
compile project (':gaugeLibraryy')
```

Comment: Does Android Studio give any other detail about the error?

Comment: no just Error:(143) Attribute "showText" has already been defined

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer... I'm just putting here since it is too big for a comment.

Checking android SDK, it seems that an attribute with that name exists:

```
<declare-styleable name="Switch">
    ...
    <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

So, I believe that some style.xml/theme.xml is defining `android:showText` twice.
Could you please search in whole project (Ctrl+H) and search for `android:showText`? Just to ensure that it was not added twice in same style/theme.

Then, please, let me know the results... I'll update the answer